# Replace a specific portion of string after a specific starting substring using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string like this

```
"This is an example. Start color=BLUE and rest of the string"
```

I want to find "color=" coming after "Start" and replace "color=BLUE" with "color=None".

"color=BLUE" always comes after "Start". But "Start" can be anywhere in the entire string.

How I can do this using regex?

Comment: i can post an answer without regex,u want it ?

Comment: sure zack, you can post that..

Comment: ,is ur problem solved ?

Comment: My problem is if color=blue is not coming after start, it should not replace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pure, efficient string methods, this works even if there are multiple `color` after `Start`:

```
Dim s = "This is an example. Start color=BLUE and rest of color=Green the string"
Dim startIndex = s.IndexOf("Start", StringComparison.Ordinal)
If startIndex = -1 Then Return s ' or do whatever you want, there is no starting point
Dim colorIndex = s.IndexOf("color=", startIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal)
While colorIndex >= 0
    colorIndex += "color=".Length
    Dim endIndex = s.IndexOf(" ", colorIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal)
    If endIndex = -1 Then Exit While
    Dim oldColor = s.Substring(colorIndex, endIndex - colorIndex) ' just out of interest
    Dim newColor = "None"
    s = $"{s.Remove(colorIndex)}{newColor}{s.Substring(endIndex)}"
    colorIndex = s.IndexOf("color=", endIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal)
End While
```

If you want to find also `start` or `COLOR`, so ignore the case, use for example `s.IndexOf("color=", startIndex, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Why so much work around sir ?

Comment: @zackraiyan:well, this is more efficient and enables better debugging or logging than regex. But maybe also because my regex skills need improvement ;-)

Comment: The patter will appear multiple place in the string. That is why i am thinking about regex. I want to avoid complex loops also.

Comment: @Sarath,u mean there will be multiple `colors` ???

Comment: If there are multiple `color` in the string,you can easily use a for each loop :)

Comment: @Sarath: well, the code is almost the same if there are multiple colors, edited by changing `If` to `While`

Comment: @Sarath,i feel a bit bad now...You should've mentioned multiple existance of `color` in your post :(

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution without regex :

```
 MyString.Replace("color=Blue","color=None")
```

The `Replace` method replaces any portion of given string with the target string.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: My problem is if color=blue is not coming after start, it should not replace...

Comment: It doesnt matter if it comes after start or not....As u mentioned,u wanted to change `color = none` to `color = blue`,it will do just that